# Logging in Rails with a per-request ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to generate a unique per-request ID in rails that I can then use for logging across a particular request.

Any solution should ideally not make too much use of the default logging code, as I'm running the application under both jruby and ruby.

Comment: Can you use `request.object_id`?

Comment: Would that be available inside models and observers as well as controllers?

Comment: I'm afraid not, you'd have to propagate it yourself, probably similar to http://www.zorched.net/2007/05/29/making-session-data-available-to-models-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 7):

Backupify produced a great article about this: http://blog.backupify.com/2012/06/27/contextual-logging-with-log4r-and-graylog/

We wanted the request_id (that is generated by rails and available at `request.uuid` to be present on all messages throughout the request. In order to get it into the rack logging (the list of parameters and the timing among others), we added it to the MDC in a rack middleware.

`application.rb:`

```
config.middleware.insert_after "ActionDispatch::RequestId", "RequestIdContext"
```

`app/controllers/request_id_context.rb:` (had trouble finding it in lib for some reason)

```
class RequestIdContext
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    Log4r::MDC.get_context.keys.each {|k| Log4r::MDC.remove(k) }
    Log4r::MDC.put("pid", Process.pid)
    Log4r::MDC.put("request_id", env["action_dispatch.request_id"])
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

If you push jobs onto delay job/resque, put the request_id into the queue. and in your worker pull it off and set into the MDC. Then you can trace the requests the whole way through

Answer (score 4):

It looks like lograge ([gem](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge)) automatically puts [`request.uuid`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/uuid) in your logs.

They have this pattern: 
`bfb1bf03-8e12-456e-80f9-85afaf246c7f`

Answer (score 2):

This is now a [feature of rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-request_id):

```rb
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def get
    puts request.request_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [NDC](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/log4r/rdoc/NDC.html) feature of [log4r](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/manual.html) is usefull to you.