# How to tag every log call in rails with request id (lograge)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, logging

I'm using lograge with rails and I have configured my logs using JSON format. I would like every time I call `logger.info`,`logger.warn`, etc. to include the request uuid. The way rails handles this with tagged logging falls short of what I would like because it does not seem able to merge the request uuid with the remainder of the JSON payload, instead prepending it on the line in non-JSON format.

For instance, if I call `logger.info(client: :ig)` I would expect the following log output:

```
{"request_id": <request uuid>, "client": "ig"}
```

But instead rails will prepend the request uuid (when configured via `config.log_tags = [:uuid]`) like so:

```
[<request uuid>] {"client": "ig"}
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the tagging behavior to merge with the JSON payload instead of prepending it on the same line? I'd like to configure our logs to forward to Splunk using just a simple JSON formatter and not deal with this prepending format.

Also, I have configured lograge to include `request_id` set to the request uuid in a lambda passed to `custom_options` in `config/application.rb`. This works but only when rails logs the request. If I explicitly call one of the logging methods anywhere else, the `request_id` is not included.

```
# application.rb
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |e|
  {
    params: e.payload[:params].except("controller", "action", "utf8"),
    request_id: e.payload[:request_id] # added this in `append_info_to_payload` in ApplicationController
  }
end
```

Then in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.log_tags = [ -> (req) { { request_id: req.env["action_dispatch.request_id"] } } ]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ben!  Did you solve this?  I am looking for the same function.

Comment: this was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35986283/1488217

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the payload doesn't have the request_id.
As you can see in:

> ./actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:18-25

```
raw_payload = {
    :controller => self.class.name,
    :action     => self.action_name,
    :params     => request.filtered_parameters,
    :format     => request.format.try(:ref),
    :method     => request.method,
    :path       => (request.fullpath rescue "unknown")
  }
```

I override this method (copy ***./actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb in config/initializer.rb***) and add your param.

```
raw_payload = {
    :controller => self.class.name,
    :action     => self.action_name,
    :params     => request.filtered_parameters,
    :format     => request.format.try(:ref),
    :method     => request.method,
    :path       => (request.fullpath rescue "unknown"),
    :request_id => env["action_dispatch.request_id"]
  }
```

Maybe there are a better way for override instrumentation, but it is enough.

Comment: s easier to override initializer with class_eval as you can see in: Access to Rails request inside ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber subclass

Answer (score 0):

Is easier to override initializer with class_eval as you can see in:
[Access to Rails request inside ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082699/access-to-rails-request-inside-activesupportlogsubscriber-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the request id to lograge using custom options:

```
  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    {
      request_id: event.payload[:request].request_id,
    }
  end
```

There is no longer a need to monkey patch other Rails classes as mentioned in the other answers.